# Wordpress get_post_limit?

Tags: wordpress

Well, i've searched for a way to get the post limit on the Dashboard (Configuration > Read > Max posts...), because I need to put this value in a WP_query.

Examples:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=$post_limit' );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress `get_option`:

```
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
```